# What is the problem with this character Á in a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

When I use this regex: `^(.*[ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú].*)(.*[\w\s].*)$` to found if a string contains accented vowels I have a problem with this Á as input. It looks like Á but it doesn't.

Example:

Regex:

```
^(.*[ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú].*)(.*[\w\s].*)$
```

Input:

```
BARRAGÁN
```

Expected: Match

Result: Match

...But with this input doesn't match:

```
BARRAGÁN
```

Expected: Match

Result: No match

**If I add this `Á` to the regex. The input match with an A without accent mark.** If I use this regex `(.*[À-ÿ].*)(.*[\w\s\.].*)` neither works. What could be happening with that letter?

Comment: That A is a base letter with a diacritic, `A\u0301`. If you want to add it to the existing regex, use `^(.*(?:[ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú]|[AEIOUaeiou]\u0301).*)(.*[\w\s].*)$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The letter is a combination of the `A` ASCII letter and a *COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT*, `\u0301` (from the Mark, nonspacing (`\p{Mn}`) category).

You may add an alternative to your current regex, that would match the allowed base letters only if they are followed with this accent mark:

```
^(.*(?:[ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú]|[AEIOUaeiou]\u0301).*)(.*[\w\s].*)$
    ^^^            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```